# converting dictionary to a linq query

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I am a newbie to c# and i'm building an application that holds content of a Library (Books and Journals).

I'm building a 3-tier program with UI, BLL and DAL.

What I'm trying to do is to get text from a combobox and convert it (eventually) in my DAL to a Linq to SQL query.
I created a local Database and mapped it with Entity framework.

I have the following code:

```
BL.MainLogic BLL = new MainLogic();
Dictionary<string, string> searchList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
searchList.Add("ItemID", cmboBxItemID.Text);
searchList.Add("ItemName", cmboBxItemName.Text);
searchList.Add("ItemType", cmboBxItemType.Text);
searchList.Add("Author", cmboBxAuthor.Text);
searchList.Add("Publisher", cmboBxPublisher.Text);
searchList.Add("Price", cmboBxPrice.Text);
DataTable searchResult = BLL.Search(searchList);
searchGridView.DataSource = searchList;
```

I'm creating a dictionary with the column name and the value to be searched by and then I pass it on to to the BL:

```
public DataTable Search(Dictionary<string,string> SearchParams)
{
    var itemType = SearchParams.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "ItemType");
    IQueryable query = SearchParams.AsQueryable();
}
```

Now what I'm trying to do is create a query from all the Keys & Values in the dictionary in the format of:

Key == Value.

How can I do that in a better way? Should I even use a dictionary for this type of action?

Comment: Maybe this link can help: [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

Comment: thanks, i ended up passing values with a class i created,
but thanks for this! :)

Comment: @yuvalos if you solved your issue please post your resolution and accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i did was i ended up passing creating a Mock-Up of my database entities that my UI can see (called it BookVO)
When the user inserts data into the comboboxes, i insert that data into a BookVO, pass that on to my BL which passes it on later to my dal. then i search my EF context using that same book.

this is where i add the book:

```
private BookVO AddNewBook()
{
    BookVO bookToAdd = new BookVO()
    {
        Author = txtBxBookAuthor.Text,
        Discount = double.Parse(txtBxBookDiscount.Text),
        Genre = txtBxBookGenre.Text,
        ISBN = txtBxBookISBN.Text,
        Name = txtBxBookName.Text,
        Price = double.Parse(txtBxBookPrice.Text),
        Publisher = txtBxBookPublisher.Text,
        ReleaseDate = DateTime.Parse(dateTimeBookPicker.Text)
    };
    return bookToAdd;
```

this is my BL part which passes the book to my DAL

```
public List<BookVO> SearchBook(BookVO book)
{
    List<Books> queryResult = BLDAL.SelectBookFromDB(book);
    List<BookVO> returnedBook = new List<BookVO>();
    foreach (Books dBBook in queryResult)
    {
        BookVO thisBook = new BookVO() {Author = dBBook.Author, Name = dBBook.Name, ISBN = dBBook.BookISBN, Discount = dBBook.Discount, Price = dBBook.Price, Publisher = dBBook.Publisher, ReleaseDate = dBBook.ReleaseDate};
        returnedBook.Add(thisBook);
    };
    return returnedBook;
}
```

this is my DAL logic for search:

```
public List<Books> SelectBookFromDB(BookVO book)
{
    var result = myEntities.Books.ToList();
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(book.Author) == false)
    {
        result = result.Where(x => x.Author == book.Author).ToList();
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(book.Name) == false)
    {
        result = result.Where(x => x.Name == book.Name).ToList();
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(book.Publisher) == false)
    {
        result = result.Where(x => x.Publisher == book.Publisher).ToList();
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(book.ISBN) == false)
    {
        result = result.Where(x => x.BookISBN == book.ISBN).ToList();
    }
    if (book.Price != 0)
    {
        result = result.Where(x => x.Price == book.Price).ToList();
    }
    if (book.Discount != 0)
    {
        result = result.Where(x => x.Discount == book.Discount).ToList();
    }

    return result;
}
```